# Usage limit of geocoder api

Tags: geocoding, google-geocoding-api

I am using Geocoder class in android to get coordinates from location name. I am not using a key, my concern is about the daily limit, the limit of 2500 requests per day is calculated per user or per app?.

Comment: Usage limits typically is calculated per API key, if API key is not present the usage will be based on public IP address. If you share IP address with somebody else, usage may be less then 2.5K daily requests.

Comment: if many users use my app (with the key) then  the limit will be less than 2.5k per user ? , but without a key every user has a limit of 2.5k (in case that he does not share ip adress )

Comment: It's possible, but keyless access may be deprecated. Last summer it happened to Google Maps JavaScript API for example.

Comment: Thw Geocoder does not have a limit at all, 2.5k is for the Google Geocoding API, not for the Geocoder class.